# Using Regex to get string between lookbehind and lookahead with brackets and parenthesis in it

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been researching using Regex in my JS project for a few hours now. I've run into an issue of trying to get the string between 'tags'. The only issue I have now is the characters I am using in the tag.

String I'm looking at:

```
[](/TABLE_1)
##Table 1
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_1)

[](/TABLE_2)
##Table 2
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_2)

[](/TABLE_3)
##Table 3
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_3)
```

I am attempting to get the string inside

```
[](/TABLE_1)
```

and

```
[](/TABLE_2)
```

Currently, I am attempting to use the Regex expression:

```
(?<=[](/TABLE_1))(.*)(?=[](/END_TABLE_1))
```

I noticed that the tags I have, which I **can't** change, are not able to be detected in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escaped `()[]` because they are recognized as metacharacters in regex and you shouldn't use `(?<=)(?=)` positive lookbehinds in JavaScript.

**Regex**: [`\[\]\(\/(TABLE_[12])\)\n([\S\s]+)\n\[\]\(\/END_\1\)`](https://regex101.com/r/uGeO1F/1)

```js
var text = `[](/TABLE_1)
##Table 1
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_1)

[](/TABLE_2)
##Table 2
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_2)

[](/TABLE_3)
##Table 3
Header 1|Header 2|Header 3
:-:|:-:|:-:
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
Value 1|Value 2|Value 3
[](/END_TABLE_3)`;

var re = /\[\]\(\/(TABLE_[12])\)\n([\S\s]+)\n\[\]\(\/END_\1\)/g;
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(text);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[2]);
    }
} while (m);
```